# FileMaker PHP API..get ID of newly created record..?

Tags: filemaker

I am using the PHP API to insert records in FileMaker.  I also need to insert related data into a separate table, so I need to pull the record ID from the new record that gets created so that I can include that ID in the new record for the related table.

Here is what I'm working with:

```
$fm =  new FileMaker('PayPal_IPN', FM_HOST, FM_USER, FM_PASS);
$new_ipn_record = $fm->createRecord('ipn_transactions', $ipn_record_data);
$new_ipn_record_result = $new_ipn_record->commit();
```

That part works as expected and adds the new record into FileMaker.  So now I need to get the ID of the record that was just created.  I tried this...

```
$new_ipn_record_id = $new_ipn_record_result->getLastRecord()->getRecordID();
```

But I end up with an error...

> Call to a member function getLastRecord() on a non-object

Any information on what I'm doing wrong here would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you should not use the internally generated RecordID as a matchfield. It will bite you when you migrate your solution to a new file and get a duplicate for every deleted record. Use an auto-entered serial number field instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$new_ipn_record_result is a boolean and not an object. I think you need to try:

```
$new_ipn_record_id = $new_ipn_record->getRecordID();
```

Comment: That's not working, which does make sense to me.  $new_ipn_record hasn't been committed yet.  $new_ipn_record_result is the result of that commit, which is where the records are loaded.  I think it might have something to do with a difference in createRecord() vs. newAddCommand(), actually.  Looking into that now.

Comment: Did you try getRecordID() on $new_ipn_record after the commit? The result of the commit() is boolean, as far as I know and not the records.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

After commiting the new record get all records and look at the last record:

```
$query = $fm->newFindAllCommand('ipn_transactions'); 
$result = $query->execute();
$records = $result->getRecords(); 
$new_ipn_record_id = $records->getLastRecord()->getRecordID();
```

Comment: There's a chance with this method that it could pull the wrong one if records are getting created close together.

Comment: That's true. You can try to count(getRecords()) before adding a new record, increment it by 1 and getRecords() after committing a new record, than using the incremented count result retrieve the record from the new getRecords() result.